# Delete record from custom sitecore 7 Index

Tags: c#, lucene, sitecore, sitecore7

I have created a custom index in Sitecore and i want to delete one record. I must mention that this index does not index sitecore items.

I am trying something like this:

```
 public void Delete(IIndexableUniqueId uniqueId)
 {
   ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(Constants.MyIndexName).Delete(uniqueId);
 }
```

Nothing happens to the index.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a custom index (not sitecore items) you should index fields representing unique id's.

```
[IndexField("_uniqueid")]
    public override IIndexableUniqueId UniqueId
    {
      get
      {
        return new IndexableUniqueId<string>("uniqueidvalue");
      }
    }
```

I will use that "uniqueidvalue" to delete from the index this way:

```
public void Delete(IIndexableUniqueId uniqueidvalue)
{
  using (IProviderDeleteContext deleteContext = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(Constants.MyIndexName).CreateDeleteContext())
  {
    deleteContext.Delete(uniqueidvalue);
    deleteContext.Commit();
  }
}
```